# Nested Executors using FixedThreadPool

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool, executor

I'm trying to implement a ExecutorService nested within another Executor. The parent executor is a FixedThreadPool of size 5, while the nested Executor is of size 10. While running it, i see the following in the logger going from "[pool-2-thread-1]" to [pool-50-thread-9]. I understand thread count going between 1 to 10 and back because the child Executor is of size 10. But why does the pool count go from 1 to 50+ and so on. Are there any memory leaks or is it because I'm shutting down the executor each time and recreating the threads

```
private  ExecutorService executors=Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);

executors.execute(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                        //code
                        logger.info(message);
                        ExecutorService childThreads = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
                        for(Map<String, Object> entity: listOfEntities){
                            childThreads.execute(new Runnable() {

                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                                try { 
                                        //code
                                        logger.info(message);
                                        //code  
                                    } catch (Exception e) {                                             
                                                e.printStackTrace();                                    
                                    }
                                }
                                }); 
                            }

                        childThreads.shutdown();
                        Long shutDownTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
                        while(!childThreads.isTerminated()) {
                            if((System.currentTimeMillis()-shutDownTime)>60000) {
                                    childThreads.shutdownNow();
                                    childThreads.awaitTermination(2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                                    break;
                            }

                        } 
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }); 
`
```

This is what i see in Logger:

```
2019-08-02 04:01:04.052  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-4]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.055  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-2]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.057  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-2]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.069  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-5]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.197  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-1]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.199  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-5]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.641  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-8]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.641  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-2]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.650  INFO 45844 --- [pool-7-thread-5]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.692  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-1]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.713  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-6]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.715  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-7]
2019-08-02 04:01:04.728  INFO 45844 --- [pool-7-thread-3]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.062  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-6]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.067  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-2]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.515  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-6]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.532  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-4]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.533  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-3]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.554  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-3]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.554  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-4]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.584  INFO 45844 --- [pool-8-thread-1]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.654  INFO 45844 --- [pool-7-thread-4]
2019-08-02 04:01:05.991  INFO 45844 --- [pool-5-thread-4]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.349  INFO 45844 --- [pool-7-thread-2]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.405  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-7]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.405  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-5]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.405  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-1]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.448  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-5]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.448  INFO 45844 --- [pool-9-thread-6]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.448  INFO 45844 --- [pool-6-thread-3]
2019-08-02 04:01:06.525  INFO 45844 --- [pool-7-thread-6]
```

Comment: _This is what i see in Logger_ I couldn't find any reference to a logger in the code you posted. Is the code you posted a [mcve] ?

Comment: I've edited my code with the logger. Basically, both the parent executor as well as the nested executor have multiple log statements. I'm using SL4j-Log4j logger FYI.